# How to differentiate $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\dots\infty}}}$?

Tags: derivatives

$$\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\dots\infty}}}$$

How to find the derivative of the above function? I am trying this question by taking the above function as y, and then I am getting $y^2=x-y$ I.e. $y^2+y-x=0$. Then from here I am getting $2$ values of $y$ I.e. $\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+4x}}2$ But I am very much confused after this because which value I should take, I can't understand.

Comment: Why not differentiate implicitly rather than finding $y$ from the quadratic?

Comment: For x>-1/4 and x<0  (sq.root(1+4x)-1)/2 will be negative and positive for all x >0 and -(1+sq.root(1+4x))/2 will always be positive for x when x >-1/4 and x<0 and negative for all x >0. So I am confused which value I should take.

Answer (score 4):

If $y^2+y-x=0$, then differentiating with respect to $x$ you get $2yy'+y'=1$, i.e., $y'=\frac{1}{2y+1}=\frac{1}{1+2\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\cdots}}}$.

Comment: I think the above function should be multiplied by 2 and have a +1 in the denominator for answer

Comment: what will be the value of y @ shyamal sayak

Comment: Because if we solve for y then there will be two values of y and here the question arises which to take?

Comment: @SubhaSankarRoy Why solve for $y$? You are defining $y$ to be $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\cdots}}$.

Comment: We have took y to be the above function. But obviously y will have two values because we are getting a quadratic equation of y

Comment: We have took y to be the above function to find the value of the above square root.

Comment: Actually I mean that x is any integer and we have a find it's value

Comment: So, I took the above expression as y and then tried for solving.

Comment: @SubhaSankarRoy If $x$ is an integer, then the expression is not differentiable.

Comment: Here in this question I have mentioned x so that  we can generalise the above expression in terms of x. Now x can take any value.

Comment: Actually first I tried to find y and then dy/dx.

Answer (score 3):

The first question to ask is what does $y=\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\ldots}}$ actually mean?  Presumably what is meant is $y = \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$, where
$y_1 = \sqrt{x}$ and $y_{n+1} = \sqrt{x-y_n}$, so
$$\eqalign{y_2 &= \sqrt{x -\sqrt{x}}\cr
           y_3 &= \sqrt{x - \sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}}\cr
           y_4 &= \sqrt{x - \sqrt{x- \sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}}}\cr
           \text{etc}}$$
The next question is for what values of $x$ does this limit exist?
For example, it does not exist at $x=1$, as we would have $y_n = 1$ for $n$ odd and $0$ for $n$ even.  For $0 < x < 1$ you run into the square root of a negative number as $y_2$, and it's not at all clear to me that there will be a real limit for any branch of the square root.  For $x > 1$ it does look to me like a limit does exist,
and since the square root should be $> 0$ it must be $(-1 + \sqrt{1+4x})/2$.

EDIT: Iteration of the map $f: y \mapsto \sqrt{x-y}$ has a $2$-cycle $(1 \pm \sqrt{4x-3})/2$ which is real for $x \gt 3/4$.  The fixed point $y_+ = (-1 + \sqrt{1+4x})/2$ is attractive for $x > 1$, as $|f'| < 1$, and $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}$ is between $y_+$ and $(1 - \sqrt{4x-3})/2$, so the limit is indeed $y_+$ for $x > 1$.